# Java reverse encoding

Tags: java, loops, decode, encode

so I'm making a program where you can either encode or decode a message using a keyword. I have the encoding part down but I'm not sure how to decode the message. I am new to java so any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code thus far:

```
            import java.util.Scanner;

            class Coder
            {
              public static void main(String[] arg)
             {
                boolean encode = false;
                boolean decode = false;
                int multi = 1;
                Scanner inputdata=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Type E to encode or D to decode:\n");
                String opt=inputdata.nextLine();
                if (opt.equals("e")||opt.equals("E"))
                {
                    System.out.print("Type the keyword to use for encoding:\n");
                    encode = true;
                }
                else if (opt.equals("d")||opt.equals("D"))
                {
                    System.out.print("Type the keyword for decoding:\n");
                    decode = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("Error:This is not an option");
                }


                if (encode==true)
                {
                    String keyword=inputdata.nextLine();
                    int[] key = new int[1000];
                    for (int k = 0; k < key.length; ++k)
                    {
                        char c = keyword.charAt(k % keyword.length());
                        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                        {
                            key[k] = c-'a';
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("Type encode message:\n");
                    String message=inputdata.nextLine();
                    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); ++i)
                    {

                        if (message.charAt(i) >= 'a' && message.charAt(i) <= 'z')
                        {
                            System.out.println((int)message.charAt(i) - (int)'a' + key[i]);
                        }
                        else if (message.charAt(i) >= 'A' && message.charAt(i) <= 'Z')
                        {
                            System.out.println((int)message.charAt(i) - (int)'A' + key[i]);
                        }
                        else if (message.charAt(i) == ' ')
                        {
                            System.out.println(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println(message.charAt(i));
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (decode==true)
                {

                }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ok. You have then enter a string as an encoding key and a string to encode. You encode and produce a bunch of numbers printed one per line. How do you enter the string to decode? A bunch of numbers?

Comment: Where did you get the code/algorithm for your encoding portion of the code?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Pretty close to a "Captain Midnight Decoder Ring" with a variable number of rings to be used in sequence as you move through the message. So key = def and msg=abc yields dfh. But it doesn't roll around at the end of the alphabet.

Comment: @LeeMeador: Yep, I've seen this sort of thing before, but I figure that he didn't make this algorithm up. If he has obtained the encoding algorithm, he surely has obtained the decoding algorithm. It's about as secure as ROT 13, but that's not the issue.

Comment: You could check out [MessageDigest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) with a SHA algorithm for decryption.

Comment: A message digest is one way. You cannot recover the original message from the digest.

Comment: You're right. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I'm unsure what kind encryption/decryption algorithm you are trying to write but it looks like it's some kind of ROT shuffle.  My best guess would be along the lines of Lee's answer but to be honest I didn't really digest your code.  It's pretty hard to read with everything inside a main function and if conditionals.

I'm guessing you are new to Java instead here are some helpful practices and code design tips to make life easier.

### JUnit is your friend:

It's a really bad idea run and debug code inside a main method.  Every time you want to examine your code you're force to manually run through each scenario and inspect the current state of the program.  You can write test programs that do all that work for you, plus it makes it easier to jump into the debugger when you need to inspect a certain condition.

JUnit is built into Java, but there are other libraries such as Hamcrest and Mockito that make it even easier to work with.

For example this all need for a basic test:

```
public class EncryptionTest {
    @Test // Test annotation marks that this method should be evaluated
    public testEncoding() {
          final String orginalString = "fooBar";
          final String expectedEncryptionResults = "barFoo"; // You should get the point.

          final String encryptedString = Encoder.encode(oringalString) 

// Or however you want to structure the encoder object.

          assertTrue( encryptedString.equals( expectedEncryptionResults ) );
          // If false, the test will fail.                                                               
    }
}
```

### Design Patterns

A good rule of thumb to keep in mind is the [Wikipedia: Law Of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Of_Demeter). Simply put, this rule states that your method or objects should know more then necessary.

#### Utils

An an easy design pattern to use is the Utility pattern.

```
public class Encoder {
    private Encoder() {} // Private constructor

    public static encode( final String message ) {
        String encodedMessage = null
        // Complex encryption magic goes here
        return encodedMessage;
    }
}
```

Since this pattern has an private constructor, you can't instantiate an Encoder object and are only able to use the static methods defined within it.  It's a good way to reuse common logic or checks,  Apache Utitls classes are a great example for the Utility pattern.

So in my Junit demo, I also used this Encoder class.

```
final String encryptedString = Encoder.encode(oringalString)
```

#### Factories

Factories are another common and easy to use design pattern.  Factories are simple objects with one goal in life, to make other objects.

```
public class EncryptionFactory {
     public String build( String message ) {
         // Complex magic goes here.
         return encryptedString;
     }
}

public class EncryptionFactoryTest {

    final EncryptionFactory factory = new EncryptionFactory();
     
     @Test
     public void testEncryption() {
            final String = originalMessage = "fooBar";
            
            final String encryptedMessage = factory.build(originalMessage);

            assertTrue( encryptedMessage.equals("barFoo") );
     }
}
```

The main benefit of using design patterns is that it pushes implementation logic such as the encryption algorithm into a smaller segment of code, making it easier to re-use and spot any errors.  Plus it also cuts down on development and maintenance time ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but I suspect you want to decode using code similar to what you have for encoding but change this:

```
(int)message.charAt(i) - (int)'a' + key[i]
```

to this:

```
(int)message.charAt(i) + (int)'a' - key[i]
```